# What's the proportion of a sample?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Is the proportion of a sample always $\overline x$, whether that sample belongs to a Bernoulli or Binomial distribution? Or is the proportion of a sample the more likelihood estimative of the probability of success? I used the likelihood function to know the best estimative of the parameter $p$, probability of success, and to Bernoulli it gave me $\widehat p = \overline x,$ and to Binomial it gave me $\widehat p = \overline x/n$ ... so, are the estimative of $p$ the fractions?